# How to partly symmetrize a multi-variables function

Tags: function-construction

For example, I want to symmetrize the variable x and z in the three-variables function f(x, y, z).I expect to obtain
1/2 f(x, y, z)+1/2 f(z, y, x). How to achieve this in Mathematica?

Comment: You actually already have the answer, simply  define:  fsym[x_,y_,z_]=1/2(f[x,y,z]+f[z,y,x])

Comment: That is good, but I expect a more general answer : if the number of variables of this function f becomes bigger, this kind of definition will not be convenient. Emmm ... Maybe I need to use the command "Permutes" to get the symmetric series about variables which I want to symmetrize, and add the variable which I want to maintain to each term by hand.

Comment: @liouville It is impossible to answer you since one has no idea what type of functions do you have in mind. It would be helpful to give a more detailed example explaining why the answer of Daniel Huber is not sufficient. Can it be that you have hundreds of variables?

Comment: Something like `Permute[f[x, y, z], GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[3], {2}]] // 
  Tr[#]/Length[#] & // Expand` perhaps?